# Why innodb locks index till the end?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, mysql-8.0, auto-increment

Why a query BETWEEN two IDs locks index till the end?

```
UPDATE elem SET c='' WHERE id BETWEEN 2 AND 5;
-- locks id>5 for some reason
```

The database is MySQL 8.0.33 GA.

Here's the full example, taken from the book "Efficient MySQL Performance" by Daniel Nichter.

```
CREATE TABLE `elem` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `a`  char(2) NOT NULL,
  `b`  char(2) NOT NULL,
  `c`  char(2) NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_a` (`a`)
);

insert into elem values
(2, 'Au', 'Be', 'Co'), 
(5, 'Ar', 'Br', 'C');

BEGIN;
UPDATE elem SET c='' WHERE id BETWEEN 2 AND 5;

select INDEX_NAME, LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_MODE, LOCK_DATA from performance_schema.data_locks;

+------------+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| INDEX_NAME | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE     | LOCK_DATA              |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| NULL       | TABLE     | IX            | NULL                   |
| PRIMARY    | RECORD    | X,REC_NOT_GAP | 2                      |
| PRIMARY    | RECORD    | X             | supremum pseudo-record |
| PRIMARY    | RECORD    | X             | 5                      |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
```

The isolation level is default (RR).

I understand why the range id=2..5 is locked. But what's the point of locking id>5?
Does it matter if someone inserts there?

P.S. Such locking happens when the upper BETWEEN condition is the last index element.

That's perfectly reproducible and was mentioned in many articles, is there a sane reason for it (dire consequences if we don't lock id>5?), or it's an imperfection of INNODB locking mechanism?

Comment: Your entire table is the only two records you're updating. What if you added 100 records and only updated two?

Comment: Since "5" is currently the end of the table, add at least two rows to the table _after_ 5; see what happens then.

Comment: The supremum locking happens only when the upper BETWEEN condition is at the end of the index.

Added the clarification to the post. The Q: is there a sane reason for it, or it's an imperfection of INNODB locking mechanism? I can't see any Repeatable Read problem if someone inserts id=6.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 now sets [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2 (auto increment interleaving)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) by default

According to [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)

> In this lock mode, auto-increment values are guaranteed to be unique and monotonically increasing across all concurrently executing “INSERT-like” statements. However, because multiple statements can be generating numbers at the same time (that is, allocation of numbers is interleaved across statements), the values generated for the rows inserted by any given statement may not be consecutive.

You asked in your question

> I understand why the range id=2..5 is locked. But what's the point of locking id>5? Does it matter if someone inserts there?

The short answer is yes since InnoDB is simply preserving the monotonic increase of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html

> When InnoDB scans an index, it can also lock the gap after the last record in the index.

it's likely checked if this is the last record in the index and therefore the gap between it and supremum is locked as well.